# How to find a specific color in one picture?

Tags: image-processing, color

In a picture, there are many different colors. How can I just want to find the position of one color. In the following picture, if I would like to find the coordinates of the position of blue, how can I achieve that? Thank you very much! [image]

Comment: By `Blue` you mean `RGBColor[0,0,1]`? Is `PixelValuePositions` ok?

Comment: @Kuba I think that is a good answer. `image = Import["1wEvU.jpg"]; PixelValuePositions[image, Blue, 0.4]` gave me `{{1605, 810}, {1606, 810}, {1604, 809}, {1605, 809},`  ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wEvU.jpg"];
```

Look for anything within 0.3 of Blue:

```
pv = PixelValuePositions[image, Blue, .3]

{{1614, 784}}
```

Just one pixel is that close to pure Blue. To display it:

```
HighlightImage[image, pv, "HighlightColor" -> White, 
  Method -> {"DiskMarkers", 20}]
```

It's over by the Balloon(?).

[image]

Comment: Ooh, I've never come across `HighlightImage` before. +1, but why is it community wiki?

Comment: @SimonWoods :) Too long to be yet another comment-as-answer, but didn't want to snatch credit away from commenters...

Comment: @cormullion Can PixelValuePositions be used to find some "strange" color?

Comment: @kathyLL any color will work, if you know its RGB values. But strangeness needs defining! :)

Comment: @cormullion Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KathyLL if you're happy with the answer it's good form to accept it. (Click on the green checkmark below the voting arrows).