# How to count the number of eggshells in the image

Tags: image-processing, image, counting

My goal for this is to simply count the number of eggshells in the image.

[image: eggshells]

Using color negate only leads to this

```
shell = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJLJX.jpg"];
binshell = FillingTransform[ColorNegate[Binarize[shell]]]
```

[image: negate]

With luck, I at least came up with something clearer using

```
binshell = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[shell, 25];
```

[image: binarize]

What is the best way to count the total number of eggshells?

Comment: Are these photos always white on a green background? That would help separating items a lot.

Comment: Yep. I specifically chose green background.

Comment: Try `ColorQuantize` with parameter 2 (or maybe 3 or 4).

Comment: Tried ColorQuantize. Using colornegate after only makes the whole image white. I however tried detecting all the white stuff using this as guide [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35132/how-to-find-a-specific-color-in-one-picture) but this is merely the result [link](https://imgur.com/a/vdT1pK9)

Comment: Very ad hoc, with too much magic: `Import["https://i.imgur.com/PZNt7JQ.jpg"] // ColorSeparate[#, "S"] & // Binarize[#, 0.25] & // ColorNegate // Dilation[#, 5] & // MorphologicalComponents // Max` `(* 11 *)`

Comment: @kirma Thank you very much! That's awesome. If it's alright, it would be nice to maybe get a visual of how they're counted. Till then, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Replace `Max` with `Colorize`, and it shows different values with different colors.

Comment: Also got to do it by using the functions step-by-step. Thanks again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
{r, g, b} = ColorSeparate[Import["https://i.imgur.com/PZNt7JQ.jpg"]];
bw = MorphologicalBinarize[b, 0.5]
```

[image]

```
ComponentMeasurements[bw, #Count > 200 &] // Length
11
```

Comment: Or `Max@MorphologicalComponents@SelectComponents[bw, "Area", # > 200 &]` in pre-v11.