# Separate colours of an image

Tags: image-processing, color, built-in-symbols

Since LAB colour space is based on [opponent color theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opponent_process), an image in 'LABColor' is made up of red/green, yellow blue separations.

I am trying to separate an image into its distinct colour components (red, green, yellow, blue, and black) this should be possible, since [it is impossible for a pixel to be both yellow/blue or red/green](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_color).

I can separate and colour the `LAB` channels fairly easily, which combines (using `ImageMultiply`) to closely resemble the original:

```
turner1 = ImageResize[Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/The_Dark_Rigi%2C_the_Lake_of_Lucerne%2C_Showing_the_Rigi_at_Sinrise_by_Turner.jpg/1599px-The_Dark_Rigi%2C_the_Lake_of_Lucerne%2C_Showing_the_Rigi_at_Sinrise_by_Turner.jpg"],400];
colspace = "LAB"; lab = ColorSeparate[turner1, colspace]; 
exp =.5; {p, q} = ColorConvert[#,"RGB"] & /@ (ColorCombine[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, colspace] & /@ 
{{#[[1]]^exp, #[[2]],  Binarize[#, 1] &@#[[3]]}, {#[[1]]^exp,  Binarize[#, 1] &@#[[2]], #[[3]]}} &@lab);
Grid[Show[#, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ #&/@ {{p, q}, {turner1, ImageMultiply[p, q]}}]
```

[image]

and then I can set `exp = .25`, and use

```
Grid[Show[#,ImageSize->300]&/@#&/@{{ImageRecolor[p, ColorsNear[Green, .4] -> White],
ImageRecolor[p, ColorsNear[Red, .25] -> White]},{ImageRecolor[q, ColorsNear[Yellow, .2] -> White],
ImageRecolor[q, ColorsNear[Blue, .6] -> White]}}]
```

to separate them into 4 channels:

[image]

and despite the second color separation being a bit trial and error, I can `ImageMultiply` all 4 images to give

[image]

which isn't too far off. What I can't do, having tried `SetAphaChannel`, `RemoveBackground`, etc. is to separate the lightness channel:

[image]

from the red, green, blue and yellow channels. How should I go about taking all the black tones out of these?

**Update**

Ok, I've made *some* progress, but it produces a somewhat desaturated image when compared to the original:

```
{r,s} = ColorConvert[#,"RGB"] & /@ (ColorCombine[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, "LAB"] & /@ 
{{#[[1]]^exp, #[[2]],  Binarize[#, 1] &@#[[3]]}, {#[[1]]^exp,  Binarize[#, 1] &@#[[2]], #[[3]]}} &@lab);
{g,h}={ImageAdd[r,ColorNegate[ColorSeparate[turner1, "LAB"][[1]]^exp]],ImageAdd[s,ColorNegate[ColorSeparate[turner1, "LAB"][[1]]^exp]]};
{k,l}={ImageAdd[g,ColorNegate@ImageRecolor[g, ColorsNear[Black, 1] -> White]],ImageAdd[h,ColorNegate@ImageRecolor[h, ColorsNear[Black, 1] -> White]]};
Grid[Show[#, ImageSize -> 300] & /@#&/@Partition[{k,l,turner1,
ImageMultiply[ColorSeparate[turner1, "LAB"][[1]],ImageMultiply[{k,l}]]},UpTo@2]]
```

[image]

Comment: You may succeed with `DominantColors` in such a way: `colors = DominantColors[turner1,     Automatic, {"CoverageImage", "Color"}];ImageMultiply @@@ colors`.

Comment: @usrr64494 yes, I'm familiar with that method, but it's not what I'm after, I'm afraid

Comment: Even the result of  `DominantColors[turner1, 20]` includes neither red nor green.

Comment: The luminance is in the L of LAB, so why not just use that? I am not understanding the question as your images contain mixtures of colours, not single colours. Also Yellow and Black aren't orthogonal to Red/Green/Blue, yellow is Red+Green, and Black is just the absence of all three. Are you sure you don't want something [more like this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/251007/72682) where I've extracted masks of r/y/g/b hues ?

Comment: @user64494 no, but the LAB colour space is based on [opponent color theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opponent_process), hence the red/green, yellow blue separations

Comment: @flinty I'm not sure yet, but thanks for the link, I'll check it out and get back to you if it works :)